# Formation of Unit Vectors as $N-1$ Dimensional Sphere

Tags: optimization, vector-analysis, maxima-minima

From a part on proving the Hessian criterion for the existence of minima and maxima in the book Vector Calculus (Colley S.).

It states that in $R^n$, the set of all unit vectors forms an $N-1$ dimensional sphere $S$, which is compact.

Please elaborate why the set of all unit vectors form an $N-1$ dimensional sphere rather than $N$ which seems more appropriate to my imagination.

Comment: Would you consider a circle in the plane more of a one-dimensional object or more of a two-dimensional object?
What about a sphere in 3-space?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't quite get what you are pertaining about. But, in accordance to the question, shouldn't the unit vectors fully occupy $R^n$ ? Like a circle in $R^2$, or a sphere in $R^3$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "fully occupy"?
Unit vectors in $R^2$ form a circle which is a curve instead of a solid region with area.
Curves are intuitively classified as an 1-dimensional object "intrinsically".
There is a technical definition for lower dimensional objects embedded in some higher dimensional space called manifolds.
The way the textbook uses the term dimension is leaving out a huge chunk of mathematical formalism, namely, manifolds.

Comment: At my educational level, I cannot fully understand the concept since it requires topology, however your statement clarified most of my concerns. I usually think of unit vectors as "occupiers" of the dimension that they are in like thinking of them as a basis, your statement made me correct some of my knowledge on these topics.